# Creating generic subscriber in kinetic (C++11)

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, c++11

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying go create a generic subscriber as in [this wiki example](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_type_introspection/Tutorials/GenericTopicSubscriber). But when I try catkin_make with the example code, it gives me `error: ‘ROSTypeList’ was not declared in this scope static std::map<std::string,ROSTypeList> registered_type;`

I am a noob to ROS. I searched the files of the **ros_type_introspection** pkg installation for `ROSTypeList` in the **ros_type_introspection** namespace but couldn't find anything similar. However this is typedef'ed [in here in parser.hpp](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/ros_type_introspection/html/files.html) but it is for **jade** as I understand. There is no **parser.hpp** or a `ROSTypeList` [in here which is for kinetic](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/ros_type_introspection/html/files.html). What am I doing wrong?

---

I did both apt installation and package installation from git in order to install **ros_type_introspection**. Both gives the same output. Here's the full catkin_make error

```
[ 97%] Building CXX object loggertest/CMakeFiles/logging_server.dir/src/gen_sub.cpp.o
[ 97%] Built target loggertest_generate_messages
/home/teshanl/catkin_ws/src/loggertest/src/gen_sub.cpp: In function ‘void messageCallback(const ConstPtr&, const string&)’:
/home/teshanl/catkin_ws/src/loggertest/src/gen_sub.cpp:26:31: error: ‘ROSTypeList’ was not declared in this scope
static std::map<std::string,ROSTypeList> registered_type;
                            ^
/home/teshanl/catkin_ws/src/loggertest/src/gen_sub.cpp:26:42: error: template argument 2 is invalid
static std::map<std::string,ROSTypeList> registered_type;
                                        ^
/home/teshanl/catkin_ws/src/loggertest/src/gen_sub.cpp:26:42: error: template argument 4 is invalid
/home/teshanl/catkin_ws/src/loggertest/src/gen_sub.cpp:29:10: error: ‘ROSTypeFlat’ does not name a type
static ROSTypeFlat flat_container;
        ^
/home/teshanl/catkin_ws/src/loggertest/src/gen_sub.cpp:34:23: error: request for member ‘find’ in ‘registered_type’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
if( registered_type.find( datatype ) == registered_type.end() )
                    ^
/home/teshanl/catkin_ws/src/loggertest/src/gen_sub.cpp:34:59: error: request for member ‘end’ in ‘registered_type’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
if( registered_type.find( datatype ) == registered_type.end() )
                                                        ^
/home/teshanl/catkin_ws/src/loggertest/src/gen_sub.cpp:36:17: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘typelist’
    ROSTypeList typelist = buildROSTypeMapFromDefinition(datatype, definition);
                ^
/home/teshanl/catkin_ws/src/loggertest/src/gen_sub.cpp:37:20: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘int’ and ‘const string {aka const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’)
    registered_type[datatype] = typelist;
                    ^
/home/teshanl/catkin_ws/src/loggertest/src/gen_sub.cpp:37:33: error: ‘typelist’ was not declared in this scope
    registered_type[datatype] = typelist;
                                ^
/home/teshanl/catkin_ws/src/loggertest/src/gen_sub.cpp:43:22: error: ‘const ConstPtr {aka const class boost::shared_ptr<const topic_tools::ShapeShifter>}’ has no member named ‘size’
buffer.resize( msg.size() ); 
                    ^
/home/teshanl/catkin_ws/src/loggertest/src/gen_sub.cpp:47:21: error: ‘_ros_type_map’ was not declared in this scope
buildRosFlatType( _ros_type_map, 
                    ^
/home/teshanl/catkin_ws/src/loggertest/src/gen_sub.cpp:51:22: error: ‘flat_container’ was not declared in this scope
                    &flat_container // the output
                    ^
/home/teshanl/catkin_ws/src/loggertest/src/gen_sub.cpp:52:19: error: ‘buildRosFlatType’ was not declared in this scope
                );
                ^
/home/teshanl/catkin_ws/src/loggertest/src/gen_sub.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
/home/teshanl/catkin_ws/src/loggertest/src/gen_sub.cpp:70:30: error: ‘DataStreamROS’ has not been declared
    callback = boost::bind( &DataStreamROS::topicCallback, this, _1, topic_name ) ;
                            ^
/home/teshanl/catkin_ws/src/loggertest/src/gen_sub.cpp:70:60: error: invalid use of ‘this’ in non-member function
    callback = boost::bind( &DataStreamROS::topicCallback, this, _1, topic_name ) ;
                                                            ^
loggertest/CMakeFiles/logging_server.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'loggertest/CMakeFiles/logging_server.dir/src/gen_sub.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [loggertest/CMakeFiles/logging_server.dir/src/gen_sub.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1154: recipe for target 'loggertest/CMakeFiles/logging_server.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [loggertest/CMakeFiles/logging_server.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301780/creating-generic-subscriber-in-kinetic-(c++11)/) by [teshansj](https://answers.ros.org/users/37224/teshansj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 168 on 2018-08-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-28**:
#q301009 also reported problems with the example on the wiki, but the OP of that question never reported it to the author of `ros_type_introspection`. I would encourage you to post this on the [issue tracker](https://github.com/facontidavide/ros_type_introspection/issues), as it could ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-28**:
.. be that the examples just need to be updated.

If you do post on the issue tracker, please comment here with a link to the issue so we keep things connected.

**Comment by [teshansj](https://answers.ros.org/users/37224/teshansj/) on 2018-08-28**:
The example code from facontidavide's [this git repo](https://github.com/facontidavide/type_introspection_tests) works fine so I ended up using it. The approach there is little different but the code does the same thing. Example code in ROS Wiki must be updated for kinetic

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-28**:\

> Example code in ROS Wiki must be updated for kinetic

exactly. So it would be nice if you could report that to the author.

**Comment by [teshansj](https://answers.ros.org/users/37224/teshansj/) on 2018-08-28**:
[I just did](https://github.com/facontidavide/ros_type_introspection/issues/23)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am the author of the library. My bad, the Wiki is very obsolete and the API changed in the following versions.

Please refer to the examples here :

https://github.com/facontidavide/type_introspection_tests

and

https://github.com/facontidavide/type_introspection_tests/blob/master/example/subscribe_example.cpp

And if you have any question, please let me know.

Davide

---

Originally posted by [Davide Faconti](https://answers.ros.org/users/578/davide-faconti/) with karma: 308 on 2018-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-09**:
Davide: would it make sense to delete the example on the wiki and refer users to the Github repository?